Dynamic Filtering by two values
I have an analysis that references a table named. The analysis finds and compares two values in two columns in the table - how many rows in the table have values for both of those columns. Who has gotten retro pay, and who has gotten paid in a particular month.

In cell B2 (cell with the 266 value) I have the following formula:
=ROWS(FILTER(Duplicates, Duplicates[Retro Units]*Duplicates[December]))

I want to, instead of having the word December as the reference for the table column, I want to pull the name from the A column (the months column). I have something like this:
I have also tried making the formula a text and using various expressions like INDIRECT(e2)
I could alternatively just manually find and replace for each new month, replacing the word of the month based on the row, I am just interested in doing this as an excel formula and not with VBA.
But it would work.

You could try using INDIRECT() function in the following way, as commented above:
=INDIRECT("Duplicates["&E2&"]")


Therefore, the final formula:
=ROWS(FILTER(Duplicates, Duplicates[Retro Units]*INDIRECT("Duplicates["&E2&"]")))


Or, better to avoid INDIRECT() function since its Volatile in nature, and keeps recalculating every time there is a change in any open workbook, that said, use the following:
=ROWS(FILTER(Duplicates,Duplicates[Retro Units]*(CHOOSECOLS(Duplicates,XMATCH(E2,Duplicates[#Headers])))))


And one more thing instead of ROWS() use SUM() as follows:
=SUM(TAKE(--(FILTER(Duplicates,Duplicates[Retro Units]*(CHOOSECOLS(Duplicates,XMATCH(E2,Duplicates[#Headers]))))<>""),,1))



If the months are in a subsequent order in your duplicates table you can calculate the column based on the row for which you want the value and then use TAKECOL
=ROWS(FILTER(Duplicates,Duplicates[Retro Units]*CHOOSECOLS(Duplicates,5-ROW()+2)))

You have to adjust the logic for CHOOSECOLS(Duplicates,5-ROW()+2) based on your configuration.

